# Input not update

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to transfer data from 1 page to another. However, when I programmatically update the input field, it will return me an empty field if I don't manually edit the field afterwards. I'm unsure if the way I'm doing it is incorrect or if there's another method for this.

Another issue I've faced, it usually takes 2 clicks for the button to update the input field. I think it's an issue with needing to wait for a response from the API(Arcgis) I'm calling. However, I'm unsure of how to fix this issue

HTML

```html
<form id="container_categorySelect" [formGroup]="details" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <img src="Location_Icon.svg" id="locationIcon" (click)="getLocation()">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="addressSelect" type="text" placeholder="Address" formControlName="location" [(value)]="currentPosition">
    <button mdbBtn type="submit" id="submitBtn" mdbWavesEffect> Locate </button>
</form>
```

Typescript

```typescript
  details:FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    category: new FormControl(''),
    location: new FormControl('')
    }
  );
  currentPosition: string;
  curLocation: any;

constructor(private router: Router,
    private addressService:AddressServicesService, 
    ) {}

// Retrieve location based on current location
  getLocation(){
    // Checks if GPS is supported
    if(navigator.geolocation){
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(response => {

        // Retrieves address based on coordinates
        this.curLocation = this.addressService.retrieveLocation(response);
        this.currentPosition = this.curLocation.address.ShortLabel
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this device")
    }
  }
```

addressService Service

```typescript
  // Retrieve Location Variables
  currentLocation: any;
  reverseGeo: string = "https://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/reverseGeocode?f=pjson&featureTypes=&location=";

  // Retrieves location based on coordinates
  retrieveLocation(position:any){
    this.http.get(this.reverseGeo + position.coords.longitude+"%2C"+position.coords.latitude).subscribe(response =>{
      // Converts response(Object) to type "any"
      this.currentLocation = response;
    });
    return this.currentLocation;
  }
```

Comment: Remove `[(value)]="currentPosition"` and change `currentPosition: string;` to `get currentPosition(): string { return this.details.get('location').value}`

Comment: @OwenKelvin I'm using [(value)]="currentPosition" to change the value of the input field in the getLocation() method. Is there a better way to update the input and the form group together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are binding to the value property and also provide a `formControlName`. Its like setting y = x; and y = p; and expect both y to be x and y to be p. Only one of them will be applied not a behavior you want in your app

With the above said, the html should now be

```html
<form id="container_categorySelect" [formGroup]="details" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <img src="Location_Icon.svg" id="locationIcon" (click)="getLocation()">
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" id="addressSelect" type="text" placeholder="Address" formControlName="location" >
    <button mdbBtn type="submit" id="submitBtn" mdbWavesEffect> Locate </button>
</form>
```

To make the code easier, I will Inject the `FormBuilder` class into our constructor and use it to create the form

```typescript
  constructor(..., private fb: FormBuilder) {}
  details = this.fb.group({
    category: [],
    location: []
  });
```

Next to update the value, you can simply use the `setValue()` function on FormControl

Simply change the line `this.currentPosition = this.curLocation.address.ShortLabel;` to

```typescript
const currentPosition = this.curLocation.address.ShortLabel;
this.details.get('location').setValue(currentPosition)
```

Your code should now look like this

```typescript
  getLocation() {
    // Checks if GPS is supported
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(response => {
        // Retrieves address based on coordinates
        console.log("getting");
        this.curLocation = this.addressService.retrieveLocation(response);
        const currentPosition = this.curLocation.address.ShortLabel;
        this.details.get('location').setValue(currentPosition)
      });
    } else {
      alert("Geolocation is not supported by this device");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngOnChanges()` to see if the input is present or not. You can pause the HTML if the required `@Input()` is not yet present using `*ngIf`.